# What does real-time safe means?

Tags: ros, ros2, real-time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have read some ROS tutorials and articles on the web referring to "real-time safe". I do know what "real-time" means but I don't know what "real-time safe" means. Do they have the same meaning? Maybe it is a similar term like "thread safe" but for real-time.

For example this ROS2 article uses it a lot:

https://design.ros2.org/articles/realtime_background.html

Best,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/331650/what-does-real-time-safe-means?/) by [Nochika](https://answers.ros.org/users/45065/nochika/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-08-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Maybe it is a similar term like "thread safe" but for real-time.

Yes, I think you can use that analogy.

Essentially it implies that *if* whatever code you add supports deterministic execution, *then* the underlying ROS 2 primitives, implemented by the various ROS 2 libraries, will not "interfere" with that determinism.

So anything "real-time safe" is safe to use in a system requiring deterministic execution (ie: real-time).

Which specific grade of real-time-ness that would be (ie: soft, hard or best effort) is not made clear, but in general hard real-time suitability is what is meant.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2